# Error a la hora de obtener un listado de entidades seleccionadas tras un include con EF Core 5

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

En un controlador de mi web API intento obtener una lista de entidades UTe

```
[HttpGet("ofertasiniciales")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<UTE>>> GetUTEsOfertasIniciales()
    {
      return await _context.Ofertas.Include(o => o.UTEs).Where(o => o.FechaPresentacionFulcrum.Year >= DateTime.Now.Year).Select(o => o.UTEs).ToListAsync();
    }
```

Pero me sale siempre este error que no logro entender

[image: error]

Como que no puede convertir

System.Collections.Generic.List<Boletus_back_end.Domain.UTE> a System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Boletus_back_end.Domain.UTE> ???

Alguna idea, por favor?

Salu2

Answer (score 0):

pudes cambiar el tipo que retorna esa accion de IEnumerable a List

```
 public async Task<ActionResult<List<UTE>>> GetUTEsOfertasIniciales()
```

tambien para mejorar el rendimiento puedes aplicar primero el Where y luego el include, de esta manera aplicas el include solo a las entidades que necesitas

```
return await _context.Ofertas.Where(o => o.FechaPresentacionFulcrum.Year >= DateTime.Now.Year).Include(o => o.UTEs).Select(o => o.UTEs).ToListAsync();
```